# Salesforce service cloud - scripts

Tags: case, cti, call-center

There are cases where during the call, the call center agent follows a script to manage the customer/case. How can i embed this script within Salesforce so that durnig the call, the agent has help?
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Options that spring to mind, simply document process in a knowledge article (negotiate this when licensing as it is often given for free as a bonus) but perhaps more advanced would be a visual workflow that integrates case creation and script steps?

Comment: The Lightning Flows would help in this scenario. You can set up a series of screens with decision points and even automate actions off the back of those responses. Even better, with Einstein "Next Best Action" you can recommend a script based on what the customer is saying. Let me know if you have additional questions

Comment: Perfect, Thank you :) This is what i had in mind, although i asked in case there is something different! Thanks!

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer so it might help others looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lightning Flows would help in this scenario. You can set up a series of screens with decision points and even automate actions off the back of those responses.

Even better, with [Einstein "Next Best Action"](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/einstein-next-best-action) you can recommend a script based on what the customer is saying.